# A "simple" Facebook share - Open Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I give up! Been trying for a week now.

What I want to do:
I have a website with a quiz, where I want the visitors to be able to share their score on Facebook. Simple right? no...

I have been looking into the Facebook / Open Graph / Custom Stories ect. but I am getting nowhere, somebody help me.

What I have learned so far is that I need to have this on the website:

Works:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Funny quiz" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="I have scored X points on this quiz" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.website.com" />
```

Does not work:

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Website Quiz" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.website.com/image.jpg" /> 
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
```

I have wasted hours on the Facebook developers site: "Open Graph Object Debugger", "Graph API Explorer" ect. ect.

I have tried to follow the guides on the developers site. Even the "Creating Custom Stories". Also I have tried to find answers elsewhere, Stackoverflow and searchengines but Google is not my friend :( Also YouTube is to no use. I have even tried to see how Buzzfeed does it, by look in there sourcecode - nothing!

Does anybody have a working example, or tutorial for dummies I can use?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by works/does not work? Is it the image that does now show?

Have you included the actual link:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<the link to your site/the current quiz>">?
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to wait 24 hours for Facebook to crawl your site before the image will work. I've had the same issue before and the next day it worked fine without any changes.

Also, make sure you have your opening html tag like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```